# How to Mount a Samba Share on Ubuntu 20.04 server for Raspberry Pi 4/400

Tags: 20.04, fstab, raspberrypi, automount

I have been trying very hard to mount a samba share.  The following works well in all x86-based Ubuntu 20.04.  But it fails to mount in Raspberry Pi based Ubuntu 20.04.

```
//192.168.1.5/Media /mnt/smb cifs guest,_netdev,uid=ronny 0 0
```

It appears /etc/fstab is different too between the two platforms.  Would this be the reason?

**on x86:**

```
UUID=a1e8f10b-a17d-49ef-aa65-1862db39786f / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
//192.168.1.5/Media /mnt/smb cifs guest,_netdev,uid=ronny 0 0
```

**on RaspPi:**

```
LABEL=writable  /        ext4   defaults        0 1
LABEL=system-boot       /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults        0       1
//192.168.1.5/Media /mnt/smb cifs guest,_netdev,uid=ronny 0 0
```

I hope someone can show me the way out of this darkness.

**Update:**

Whe I run `sudo mount -a`, it mounts successfully.  It's when the Raspberry Pi is rebooted/started is when it failed to mount.  here's what's on /var/log/syslog:

```
Sep 12 21:01:05 containers2 systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/smb...
Sep 12 21:01:05 containers2 systemd[1]: mnt-smb.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Sep 12 21:01:05 containers2 systemd[1]: mnt-smb.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 12 21:01:05 containers2 systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/smb.
```

Comment: Do you get an error message "when it fails to mount?" Do you get an error message if you enter `sudo mount -a` in a terminal of your Pi?

Comment: @user68186, when I use sudo mount -a, it mounts successfully.

however, when I do a grep smb /var/log/syslog, I get the following error.  I've Googled like hell to understand that it means. 

Sep 12 21:01:05 containers2 systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/smb...
Sep 12 21:01:05 containers2 systemd[1]: mnt-smb.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Sep 12 21:01:05 containers2 systemd[1]: mnt-smb.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 12 21:01:05 containers2 systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/smb.

Comment: It looks like fstab is waiting for the network to be up and running before trying to mount the share. I found a couple of solutions by Google: Try them one at a time: The first is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756566/fstab-mount-network-share-with-guest) It adds `x-systemd.automount` to the line in `/etc/fstab`. The [second one is here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349264/fstab-mount-wait-for-network). It adds `x-systemd.after=network-online.target`.

Comment: Let me know if either of them works. I will convert my comment to an answer. Then you can accept the answer as correct. Or you can write your own answer.

Comment: The first link works!

Comment: The second link didn't work. Here are the two /etc/fstab command.  The first one works!  The second didn't work unless I missed something in that command. 

//192.168.1.5/Media /mnt/smb cifs guest,_netdev,x-systemd.automount 0 0

//192.168.1.5/Media /mnt/smb cifs guest,x-systemd.after=network-online.target 0 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like systemd does not respect the option `_netdev`. This means `/etc/fstab` is trying to mount the samba share before the network is up and running.

Modify your `/etc/fstab` to look like this:

```
//192.168.1.5/Media /mnt/smb cifs guest,_netdev,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756566/fstab-mount-network-share-with-guest

The `systemd.automount` option mounts the samba share "on demand".

Hope this helps